# Can't get rid of underfull \hboxs

Tags: spacing, warnings

I've been trying to get rid of a bunch of underfull `\hbox` warnings in my cv.  A minimal example of what I am dealing with is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newcommand\Job[3]{{\bf #1}, #2\\ #3}

\newcommand\LongestDate{\widthof{7777 (Spring)}}
\newcommand\DatedItem[2]{
    \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}[t]{@{\hspace{0.25in}}p{\LongestDate}@{\hspace{0.125in}}p{\linewidth - \LongestDate - 0.375in}@{}}
            #1 & {\raggedright #2}
    \end{tabular*}}

\begin{document}

\DatedItem{2013--}{\Job{Rice University}{Houston, TX}{Associate Professor}}

\end{document}
```

I've tried inserting `\hfill`'s in various places (like before all the `\\`) and also adding a bunch of `\raggedright`'s.  But nothing seems to get rid of the warnings.  I should remark that everything is typeset like I want -- I just want it to compile with no warnings!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used `\par` not `\\` (usually), used `\textbf` not `\bf` (which shouldn't be used in latex) and added a missing `\par` in the scope of `\raggedright` (otherwise it does nothing) and use `tabular` not `tabular*` (`tabular*` can do nothing unless you add stretch glue between the columns).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newcommand\Job[3]{\textbf{#1}, #2\par #3}

\newcommand\LongestDate{\widthof{7777 (Spring)}}
\newcommand\DatedItem[2]{%
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{\hspace{0.25in}}p{\LongestDate}@{\hspace{0.125in}}p{\linewidth - \LongestDate - 0.375in}@{}}
            #1 & {\raggedright #2\par}
    \end{tabular}}

\begin{document}

\DatedItem{2013--}{\Job{Rice University}{Houston, TX}{Associate Professor}}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you might consider this simpler alternative. You can customize the list's appearance using the `enumitem` package if you like.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\Job}[3]{%
    \textbf{#1}, #2\newline #3%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item[2013--] \Job{Rice University}{Houston, TX}{Associate Professor}
\item[2000--2012] \Job{Harvard University}{Boston, MA}{Assistant Professor}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  However, the problem with this is that it does not ensure constant indenting throughout the document, and it is important that everything "lines up".  To see what I mean, here is my cv: http://www.math.rice.edu/~andyp/cv.pdf